# Make Matlab print the complex unit as "j" instead of "i"

Tags: python, matlab, complex-numbers

I want to print complex data to a text-file using Matlab. Afterwards I want to read the data using Python (via the open() function for example). However, Matlab prints the complex numbers like

> 1+1i

but Python would like it in the form

> 1+1j

How can I make Matlab print the complex unit as "j"? Or alternatively, how can I make Python accept "i" as the complex unit?

Comment: _how can I make Python accept "i" as the complex unit?_ you need to show us how do you communicate between MATLAB and Python. In what way data are exported from MATLAB and imported to Python?

Comment: I edited the question. I print the data to a txt file using Matlab. After that, I want to read the txt file with Python using open().

Comment: replace your i with j in text file ?

Comment: Why can't you just use `.replace('i', 'j')` on the string data in Python before you convert it to complex?

Comment: Yeah, that's possible. But if the file contains a header or other words then there also the i would be replaced with j, right?

Answer (score 2):

As you're writing to a text-file, while not just do the conversion there?

Something like

```
>> a=1+2i

a =
1.0000 + 2.0000i

>> sprintf('%f+%fj',real(a), imag(a))

ans =
1.000000+2.000000j
```

You can of course replace `sprintf` with `fprintf`.

Answer (score 0):

Could you use a regex replacement? Perhaps the one in MATLAB?

```
newStr=regexprep(str,'([\d.]+\s*[+\-]\s*[\d.]+)i','$1j');
```